# Updating a WP8 in Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I made some bugfixes to my app and I now need to update my current WP8 app with this newer version. How is this process done in the WP8 store. Do I need to upload a new app or can I adjust the current app? It's quit hard to find some information about the uploading process of an update for a WP8 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your app in Dev Center, click Update app, upload new xap file

Comment: Thanx, that was very helpfull, do you know when uploading a new xap file within the updating process you need to remove the old one? What will happen in the dev store, or do I just upload the new xap with a higher version number and the store just takes care of it?

Comment: do not remove the old one, use the Replace option

Comment: Do I have to refill all the information/images? Because it has gone, once I replaced the XAP.

Answer (score 0):

go to devwindows and then click App, see the App's lists . . choose one, then click update apps, and replace it with your new .xap